# Why can't the Kleene closure construction for an NFA be simplified?

Tags: parsing, lexer, nfa, kleene-star

Most sources, such as http://www.cs.may.ie/staff/jpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node5.html, suggest that the Kleene closure be constructed with 4 nodes.

Why can't it be constructed with just 2, as follows?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In order to get correct results when you concatenate two NFAs, you need to ensure that for both components, either:

1. There are no transitions out of the end state; or
2. There are no transitions into the start state.

The normal Thompson's construction ensures both.

Without such restrictions, composition doesn't work.  With your construction, for example, the NFA for `a*b*` also accepts `ababab`, which is wrong.

Comment: This is the right answer. It's a construction practicality constraint, not a minimized form.